# Addresses appear empty in QT wallet, but not in the blockchain

Tags: wallet, address, electrum, bitcoin-qt-setup

I tried to move from qt to electrum, so I opened a new electrum wallet and transfer a small amount to it. 
This worked fine, so I tried to transfer all the rest.

Now - the qt wallet appears to be empty, but so does the electrum wallet.
However - I ran listaddressgroupings on the qt console, and when I checked each address individually and added them up - all the bitcoins are there, so nothing went missing, but somehow my qt-wallet is oblivious to that.

I tried to wait for a week or two, but that hasn't changed.
I tried running qt with -rescan, but that hasn't worked either.

How can I make my qt wallet see balance in the addresses for what it really is?

Comment: Could you check the address at: https://blockchain.info/ ?

Comment: @WebWeave I did, and they show that the bitcoins are still there. Hasn't moved. Just my qt-wallet can't see it for some reason.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of bitcoin-qt ?

Comment: @WebWeave I wasn't, but now that I updated *and* ran it with -rescan all is well. Thanks a lot!